# Javascript / changing text background color

Tags: javascript

This piece of code places 5 random number in 5 lines and when user clicks on each number the cursor shape changes to pointer and text back ground color changes randomly.
I meant to do it in a way that when mouse goes on a text itself it turns to a pointer and color of only the text changes not the whole line. But I am not sure how to do that. Any hint ?

```
var div = document.getElementById("div1"); // There is a html file with a div tag which its ID is div1
var bgColors = ["yellow","red","green","blue","orange"];

for(counter = 0 ; counter<5; counter++){
    p = document.createElement("p");
    node = document.createTextNode(generateRandomNumer());
    p.appendChild(node);
    div.appendChild(p);
}

function bgColorChange(element){    
    element.style.backgroundColor = bgColors[Math.floor((Math.random()*5))];   
}

pTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (counter = 0; counter<pTags.length ; counter++ ){
    console.log(pTags[counter]);
    pTags[counter].style.cursor = "pointer"
    pTags[counter].addEventListener("click",function(){      
        bgColorChange(this)});
};
```

Comment: Do you mean, you only want one character to change it's colour? The Character being hovered over?

Comment: yes. That is what I meant

Comment: You need to have each character in a separate inline element to do that, then listen on each character - there is no other way without calculating the size of the characters in the browser, which varies from browser to browser